# What analysis should I perform to determine the minimum food items necessary to satisfy daily nutrient values?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, pandas

I have a table ("table A") where each row represents a single food, and each column represents the amount of a particular nutrient found in that food.

```
"food_id", "protein", "vitamin a", ...
1, 2.7, 3000 ...
2, 5.9, 1000 ...
```

I have another table ("table B") that lists recommended daily values for each nutrient.

```
"nutrient id", "nutrient name", "daily value", "unit" ...
1, "protein", 50, "g" ...
2, "vitamin a", 5000, "iu" ...
```

The units for the nutrients are the same in both tables.

Given this information, I'd like to create baskets/groups of food items from table A that satisfy the recommended daily values of all the nutrients in table B. I'd like to minimize the size of these baskets. i.e. What is the fewest number of food items that provide just enough of all the daily nutrient values? I expect there to be many possible baskets of many possible sizes. I'd like to see them all (within reason). In other words, if this analysis returns 100 baskets containing 5 food items each, 50 baskets containing 6 food items each, etc, I'm okay with that.

I'm using Python Pandas and CSV files from the FDA/USDA to do this.

What statistical analysis should I use here? What are the key words I'm looking for? Bonus: Is there a function in Pandas for it?

Comment: This is a problem in constrained optimization, not statistics. One python library for constrained optimization,  a.k.a., "linear programming," is PuLP.  PuLP is pandas friendly. https://hackernoon.com/linear-programming-in-python-a-straight-forward-tutorial-a0d152618121. There are many LP libraries available in python. N.B. Constrained optimization is an advanced semester long course. Good luck!

Comment: Whew boy! Thanks for providing a library I can check out. I'll get started learning about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

> The knapsack problem or rucksack problem is a problem in combinatorial optimization: Given a set of items, each with a weight and a value, determine the number of each item to include in a collection so that the total weight is less than or equal to a given limit and the total value is as large as possible. It derives its name from the problem faced by someone who is constrained by a fixed-size knapsack and must fill it with the most valuable items...

Check out the Simplex Method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I'll get started down the rabbit hole.